# I didn't get the essence of the highlighted sentence mentioned down below because of the way sentence is formulated. I found it difficult

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

“We all said to each other in camp that there could be no earthly happiness which could compensate for all we had suffered. We were not hoping for happiness—it was not that which gave us courage and gave meaning to our suffering, our sacrifices and our dying. And yet we were not prepared for unhappiness. **This disillusionment, which awaited not a small number of prisoners, was an experience which these men have found very hard to get over and which, for a psychiatrist, is also very difficult to help them overcome. But this must not be a discouragement to him; on the contrary, it should provide an added stimulus.**”

Excerpt From: Viktor E. Frankl. “Man's Search for Meaning.”

Comment: Perhaps in German this kind of sentence construction is more normal.

Comment: @rcook what about those sentences is uncommon in English to you? It seems perfectly normal to me, if a bit wordy.

Comment: I find it uncommonly complicated. Frankl is communicatng the disillusionment's prevalence, its difficulty, and the psychiatrist's difficulty, and something about "awaited not a small number of prisoners" just starts the whole thing off as a sentence to be struggled with, not one easily understood. I can work it out, but don't find it "perfectly normal".

Comment: @MaciejStachowski please explain it to me. I am finding it difficulty understanding. Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence talks about how, after being released from the concentration camp, many of the prisoners were expecting to return to a "normal" life - but instead they realized they're still feeling unhappiness. The "disillusionment" presumably comes from that difference between what the prisoners expected and what they ended up feeling.

The author notes that for a psychiatrist it's difficult to help such a person not to feel unhappy, but the second sentence states that they should not be discouraged from helping just because it's not easy. Instead, a psychiatrist facing such a patient should feel mobilized and more motivated to help them.